# Capacity of vector increases after inserting an element?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm really new to c++ and I'm just starting to experiment with it. Here's some code that I just went through:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {

   std::vector<int> v;
   std::cout << "Capacity of v is " << v.capacity() << '\n';

   v.resize (100);
   std::cout << "Capacity of v after resize is " << v.capacity() << '\n';

   v.insert (v.begin(), 2);
   std::cout << "Capacity of v after insert is " << v.capacity() << '\n';
}
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
Capacity of v is 0  
Capacity of v after resize is 100
Capacity of v after insert is 200
```

Now, I've read that a vector reallocates itself when the capacity has become too small e.g. due to an insertion. But I thought I had a capacity of 100? And now I just wanted to insert 2. Why does 2 not fit in the capacity of 100? I don't seem to understand that.

Comment: If you want to add more capacity, that's [`reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve), not `resize`.

Comment: Because there are already 100 elements in it with `resize`

Comment: Oh! I just realized that. Thank you very much. Seems like I mixed those two up. Really sorry for that!

Comment: just after your `resize(100);`  add this line: `for(const auto &it:v) std::cout<<it<<" ";`  and run the program. You will understand, why.

Comment: In your example code, in addition to looking at `v.capacity()`, look at `v.size()`. That will make it clearer what the effect of `v.resize(100)` is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you are confused about what `std::vector::resize` does.

It shrinks or grows the object so that it has the size that the function is given. By using

```
v.resize (100);
```

you asked that `v` be resized to 100 elements. After that, the call

```
v.insert (v.begin(), 2);
```

the size of the object will be 101. That requires the capacity to be increased if the current capacity is less than 101.

Perhaps you meant to use [`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve). It increases the capacity of the object, if necessary, without increasing its size.